# Reverse page curl from RTL to LTR

Tags: android, curl, flip

World!
I'm using [Harism Page Curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) to implement page curl in my project all thing are ok but the direction of curling.
I'm using arabic language in my app so the curl must be from Left to Right(Arabic books).

### [image]

what this library offer is curling from right to left (english books).

### [image]

so i tried the following with no succeed:

1. Reversing the image loading.
2. Changing parameters in CurlView Class.
   as shown below :

   public class CurlView extends GLSurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener,
                       CurlRenderer.Observer {

   ```
       // Shows one page at the center of view.
       public static final int SHOW_ONE_PAGE = 1;
       // Shows two pages side by side.
       public static final int SHOW_TWO_PAGES = 2;
       // Curl state. We are flipping none, left or right page.
       private static final int CURL_LEFT = 1;
       private static final int CURL_NONE = 0;
       private static final int CURL_RIGHT = 2;
       // Constants for mAnimationTargetEvent.
       private static final int SET_CURL_TO_LEFT = 1;
       private static final int SET_CURL_TO_RIGHT = 2;
       private boolean mAllowLastPageCurl = true;

       private boolean mAnimate = false;
       private long mAnimationDurationTime = 300;
       private PointF mAnimationSource = new PointF();
       private long mAnimationStartTime;
       private PointF mAnimationTarget = new PointF();
       private int mAnimationTargetEvent;

       private PointF mCurlDir = new PointF();

       private PointF mCurlPos = new PointF();
       private int mCurlState = CURL_NONE;
       // Current bitmap index. This is always showed as front of right page.
       private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

       // Start position for dragging.
       private PointF mDragStartPos = new PointF();

       private boolean mEnableTouchPressure = false;
       // Bitmap size. These are updated from renderer once it's initialized.
       private int mPageBitmapHeight = -1;

       private int mPageBitmapWidth = -1;
       // Page meshes. Left and right meshes are 'static' while curl is used to
       // show page flipping.
       private CurlMesh mPageCurl;

       private CurlMesh mPageLeft;
       private PageProvider mPageProvider;
       private CurlMesh mPageRight;

       private PointerPosition mPointerPos = new PointerPosition();

       private CurlRenderer mRenderer;
       private boolean mRenderLeftPage = true;
       private SizeChangedObserver mSizeChangedObserver;

       // One page is the default.
       private int mViewMode = SHOW_ONE_PAGE;`
   ```

and

```
 @Override
        public int getPageCount() {
            return mBitmapIds.length;
        }

        public Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory("UX")
                    .setAction("click")
                    .setLabel("submit")
                    .build());

            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            b.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);
            int margin = 0;
            int border = 0;
            Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width, height);

            int imageWidth = r.width() - (border);
            assert d != null;
            int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                    / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border)) {
                imageHeight = r.height() - (border);
                imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                        / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            }

            r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth));
            r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border;
            r.top += r.top;

            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
            c.drawRect(r, p);
            r.left += border;
            r.right -= border;
            r.top += border;
            r.bottom -= border;

            d.setBounds(r);
            d.draw(c);

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {

            if (index == i) {
                Bitmap back = loadBitmap(width, height, index);
                page.setTexture(back, CurlPage.SIDE_BOTH);
                index++;
                i++;
            } else {
                Bitmap back = loadBitmap(width, height, index);
                page.setTexture(back, CurlPage.SIDE_BOTH);
            }
        }
```

Comment: any suggestions?!